# I get regularly get déjà vu - but I know it's not a memory recall - I always think it's from a dream

Tags: neuroscience, psychology

My apologies if this is not the right forum for a neuroscientific/psychological question, especially not one coming from personal experience. Please close/move as appropriate :)

Doubtless we're all familar with déjà vu - people invariably describe it as the feeling of recalling their current situation from memory, as though they're repeating something they've experienced in real-life before.

I've regularly had this experience - it happens about once every month or two, the experience never lasts more than 5-10 seconds, and it can be unnerving. However my experience is different from what others always describe: when I'm having an episode I *know* I'm not re-experiencing something I've done in real-life before, instead I have this feeling that I'm experiencing something I've had in a dream before - a dream premonition, not a memory of real-life. After the experience fades I return to normal and recognize that I have no dream-memories of whatever it is I just experienced - *a false feeling of post-hoc premonition*.

My father reports the same as well, that he has times where he swears he's "seen this before in a dream" instead of a momentary false memory - he named the experience "breaking a dream" - no-one else seems to using the same terminology as my dad so searching for that online comes up blank. I do see very rare reports online of similar experiences but we "false-dream" deja-vu subjects are definitely in the minority.

I'm curious where my (apparently inherited) ability to slightly discern deja-vu experiences from false memories might come from, and how this "false dream-memory" vs "false real-life memory" difference has a basis in neurology.

Comment: Is this probably more suitable for cognitive science (cogsci.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Chris - nope, it's a personal question - I voted to close because of it here, and will do the same at cogSci.

Comment: @Christiaan I suspected that.